# Left Aligned Popup Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been hours trying to align this absurd code. How can I align the menu to the right?

```js
var k = 0;
function fnclick() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--display", k ? "none" : "block");
  k = 1 - k;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --display: none;
  --width: 30%;
  --height: 5%;
  --bgcolor1: #222222;
  --bgcolor2: #222299;
  --bgcolor3: #2222FF;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

a:hover,
a#mnu:hover {
  background-color: var(--bgcolor2);
}

a:active,
a#mnu:active {
  background-color: var(--bgcolor3);
}

body {}

a {
  display: var(--display, block);
  display: block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: var(--bgcolor1);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

div#navbar {
  border: 1px solid #ff1100;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a#mnu {
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  height: var(--height);
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: var(--bgcolor1);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a id="mnu" onclick="fnclick()">&#9776;</a>
  <a id="mnuExit" onclick="mnuRefr()">Exit</a>
  <a id="mnuRefr" onclick="mnuRefr()">Refresh</a>
  <a id="mnuOpts" onclick="mnuOpts()">Chart Options</a>
  <a id="mnuSlct" onclick="mnuSlct()">Select Channels</a>
  <a id="mnuSave" onclick="mnuSave()">Save Snapshot</a>
  <a id="mnuHalt" onclick="mnuHalt()">Halt Plot</a>
</div>
<div>This absurd text keeps moving with every action of the menu, and do not keep QUIET, since the menu do not float freely over the text....</div>
```

Comment: Your title is *"Left Aligned Popup Menu"*, and there is one sentence in the description that says you want it to be *"right aligned"*, while it is already right aligned, and it contradicts with title. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have an element with class **alignRight**

```
<div class="alignRight">  My Menu Item </div>
```

Now write some css for the above element

```
div.alignRight{
    display: flex;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here are 3 important lines

```
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: fixed;
```

Comment: If this is your question: How can I align the menu to the right?  Then I think I've answered it correctly. Please use the important lines.